# Performance issue when applying opacity

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm developing an android app which has a background in activity that has 4 fragments, in every fragment I have widgets (layouts that has buttons and etc). 

The problem is when I apply an opacity for these widgets the moving between the fragments becomes very slow. (without opacity everything is perfect) 
Does anyone faced this problem before, or anyone has a suggestion ? 
Thanks in advance

background xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/tab_activity_background"
android:tileMode="disabled" />
```

obacity:

```
private void setWidgetBackgroundColor()
{
    GradientDrawable backgroundDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    backgroundDrawable.setSize(WIDGET_WIDTH, WIDGET_HEIGHT);
    backgroundDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(bgColorResId));
    backgroundDrawable.setCornerRadius(WIDGET_CORNER_RADIUS);
    if(MINDOGLASS_ENABLED)
    {
        backgroundDrawable.setAlpha(opacity);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    {
        setBackground(backgroundDrawable);
    }
    else
    {
        setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
    }
}
```

fragments:

```
private class MainFragmentsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    Class[] classes = {FavoritesFragment.class, ControlsFragment.class, ActionsFragment.class, RulesFragment.class, GroupsFragment.class};
    Map<Integer, WeakReference<TileGridTabFragment>> currentFragments = new HashMap<>();
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager;


    public MainFragmentsAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager)
    {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
        this.supportFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        try
        {
            TileGridTabFragment fragment = (TileGridTabFragment)classes[position].newInstance();
            fragment.setActivity(DevicesActivity.this);
            currentFragments.put(position, new WeakReference<>(fragment));
            return  fragment;
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return classes.length;
    }

    public TileGridTabFragment getFragment(int key)
    {
        WeakReference<TileGridTabFragment> tileGridTabFragmentWeakReference = currentFragments.get(key);
        if(tileGridTabFragmentWeakReference == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return tileGridTabFragmentWeakReference.get();
    }
}}
```

without opacity: 
[image: without opacity]

with opacity:
[image: with opacity]

Comment: Can you post some code or screenshot, or maybe both?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: Where from is `setWidgetBackgroundColor()` called and how heavy in terms of MB is your image?

Comment: Every widget has a function called setOpcacity(int percent) that apply the opacity on the widget layout, the image size is 400KB (I've tried to use a very small image but the problem still exists) .

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of this page (and the links within it): https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw.html